# Animation cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, android-animation

i'm writing

```
Animation anIn;
```

but Animation error,

```
Animation cannot be resolved to a type;
```

and I don't want to import

```
android.view.animation;
```

I want to use `nineoldandroids` library. So import that library project to work-space, then right click on my project , properties, and in Android Tab reference to library in work-space.
now i can see com.nineoldandroids imports.
but error exist yet!

what's wrong?
how can i change a sample from android animation imports to `nineoldandroids` imports?

Comment: Please mention some code.

Comment: @Grishu I can't get instance from Animation. so there is no more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i see here: http://nineoldandroids.com/

There is only animation package and to animate for example a view you have to import and use `ObjectAnimator` instead of `Animation`

You can download sources of nineoldandroid and found that there is no `Animation` class at all.

[image]

**UPDATED**

Nineoldandroid library is used to support old devices with new (comes with honeycomb (api11+)) animation apis (Animators). So to use `Animation` classes which comes with api lvl 1 you don't need to use oldnineandroid, because this classes are already in all of the android phones.

You only have to use nineoldandroid if you want to use new APIs.

Link to understand =) : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1755915

Comment: So these words on that website "The API is exactly the same as the Honeycomb API, just change your imports to use com.nineoldandroids.animation.*." are Nonsense :| .

Comment: Why? It depends on what API you are using, there is ObjectAnimator class in android sdk too.

Comment: em,Some question,in past i wrote Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF ,but now there is no RELATIVE_TO_SELF in ObjectAnimator!

Answer (score -1):

Go to 'java build path' in eclipse and use add jars from there , also remove android library reference first .